# get() returned more than one Order -- it returned 2

Tags: python, django

Actually i want to build a virtual payment system but whenever a customer wants to pay his first order it proceed successfully but in the 2nd time i face this error.I dont know why i am getting this error can someone please help me to solve this problem

Here is my :

Model.py

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=1)
    email = models.EmailField( default=1)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    coin = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default=0000.00)
    # user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='customer', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.phone_number
class Order(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="product")
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=12, null=True)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    date = models.DateField(datetime.datetime.today, null=True)
    status = models.ForeignKey(Status, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    payment_method = models.ForeignKey(PaymentMethod, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    total = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.total = self.price * self.quantity
        return super().save(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

Here is my views.py:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        customer = Customer.objects.get(id=request.session['customer']['id'])
        print(customer)
        try:
            index, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer)
            # print(index.total)
        except Order.MultipleObjectsReturned:
            index = Order.objects.get(customer=customer)


        # index = Order.objects.get(customer=customer)
        # print(index.total)


        balance = request.session['customer']['coin']
        print(balance)
        if balance >= index.total:
            balance = balance - index.total
            print(balance)
            # Customer.objects.filter(id = request.session['customer']['id']).update(coin=balance)
            customer = Customer.objects.get_or_create(id = request.session['customer']['id'])
            customer.coin = balance
            customer.save()
            request.session['customer']['coin'] = balance

            return HttpResponse("Remaining balance: " + str(balance))

        return HttpResponse("Failed")
```

Comment: It means that there are two orders for the same customer, so `Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer)` can not work, since there are *two* orders that satisfy the given filter.

Comment: The fact that you later use `Order.objects.get(..)` will not solve the issue, since that will raise the *same* error.

Comment: So what is the solution for this ?? @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: Well since there are two orders, it is not clear to me *what* you want to do. Before you can *implement* something, you first need to *specify* it.

Comment: what should i do then ?? :( please help @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: As @WillemVanOnsem has said - you need to specify what it is you're wanting to do... I'll also add a side note that your modelling looks a bit odd... A single product and quantity on an `Order` doesn't make much sense - you might want to think about `Order` have the summary and related `Customer` information, but also a model called `OrderLine` or similar that contains the product and quantity and price etc with a related `Order`...

Comment: What you should do is have a single "active" order for customer, a customer may have multiple "complete" or "shipped" orders but should have a single not finalized order. I see your Order have a status attribute, work with that.

Comment: @JLeno46: well later it somehow checks a certain *balance*, so it is all rather confusing. I think that instead of trying to fix this single view, it might be better to do some remodeling, and ensure that it is clear what each model represents. For example keeping a balance in the session is a bit "unsafe", since eventually the session will be removed, but not the customer.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem Yes models need to be redone as first step

Comment: If i add order_onvoice field and make different different invoice will it solve the problem ?